# Make Container size as parent Stack size

Tags: flutter, containers, height, parent

I need draw the widget over some other content by condition. I want to align this widget as I want (using `Alignment`). I supposed that I need to use a `Stack`, i.e.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Column(), // Content
    Visibility(
      visible: isVisible, // condition is here
      child: Container(
        //height: double.infinity, // cause rendering crash
        child: Container(
          padding: ...,
          margin: ...,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('message')
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

I need that first `Container` will populate the whole place which `Stack` and place the second `Container` in any place inside first `Container`.

The desired initial condition do not use `Positioned`.

So is it possible in principle? If no, `Positioned` can be used. I am implement a-like `SnackBar` rectangle which I can place inside parent rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `heigth:double.infinity` you cant wrap into an Expanded Widget.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Column(), // Content
    Visibility(
      visible: isVisible, // condition is here
      child: Expanded( 
        child: Container(
          padding: ...,
          margin: ...,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('message')
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```